# jQuery event.target with <a> and <p> tags

Tags: jquery, zepto

I have a jQuery event for all `<a>` tags set up like this

```
$('a').live('click', function(event)
```

and I am getting the href of the tag using this

```
var href = event.target.href;
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<a href="/test/path/">
     <p>My Link</p>
</a>
```

I can successfully log `var href` in the console when I click in the area of the `<a>` tag, but when I click on the text (the `<p>` tag within the `<a>` tag), my console says 'undefined' for event.target.href and '[object HTMLParagraphElement]' for event.target.

How can I check if the user is clicking on the text and get the href value of the `<a>` tag it is child of?

Comment: why var href ? no other variable name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get your href value like this

```
$('a').live('click', function(){
  var target=$(this).attr("href");
  alert(target);
});
```

JsFiddle Sample http://jsfiddle.net/Gz6mT/7/

If you are using jQuery 1.7+, Use `.on()` to attach event handlers insted of live. live() is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 5):

Use `this` instead of `event.target`.

```
var href = this.href;
```

---

- `event.target` is the most deeply nested element clicked
- `this` is the element to which the handler is bound *(or in the case of delegation like `.live()`, it's the element that successfully matched the selector)*

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should use `.on` (if available) and at worse, `.delegate` rather than `.live`.  Other than that, you can get the `href` from the object that the event is bound to rather than the target:

```
var href = $(this).attr('href');
```

If you *really* want to use the target, you can find the closest anchor parent:

```
var href = $(event.target).closest('a').attr('href');
```